# Python subprocess run() with multiple arguments on Windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, arguments

I've run into a problem trying to start a game with some additional parameters. Normally you enter them in the "target line" on **Windows**, such as:

```
"C:\Path\To\game.exe" --arg --arg2 --arg3 abc --arg4 xyz
```

There are both arguments that are simply the argument like --arg and --arg2, then there are other arguments that require another value, such as "--arg3 50".

I have already figured out how to run multiple arguments in a fixed manner such as below, "localconfig_data["exe"]" contains the path as "C:\Path\To\game.exe".

```
subprocess.run([localconfig_data["exe"], "--editor", "--erode 100"])
```

My issue is that depending on previous selections in my program, I could end up with around 10 different arguments which makes it quite impractical to make cases for all different options.

What I've tried that doesn't work:

```
args_string = "--editor --erode 100 --hidden-hud" #args_string is made in a for loop depending on the arguments given
subprocess.run([localconfig_data["exe"], args_string])
```

Outcome is that nothing happens. My next best idea was to try to print it out:

```
args_list = ["--editor", "--erode 100", "--hidden-hud"]
subprocess.run([localconfig_data["exe"], for a in args_list: print(a)])
```

This gives me a syntax error: **SyntaxError: did you forget parentheses around the comprehension target?**, so it was a proof of concept in my mind.

Final question: how can I add all of my arguments dynamically when launching a program with subprocess.run() ?

Comment: Maybe `args_string = '--editor "--erode 100" --hidden-hud'` or (the same) `args_string = "--editor ""--erode 100"" --hidden-hud"` ?

Comment: This didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion. Figured out how to make it work, updating my post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution to this after some testing. What I ended up doing was building a string for the entire command to execute at once. First part of the string was subprocess.run() with the path, followed by a for loop with all the arguments and finally the closing brackets for the subprocess. Example below.

```
argslist = ["--arg1", "--arg2", "--arg3"]
executeString = 'subprocess.run([localconfig_data["exe"]'

for argument in argslist:
   executeString += ', "'
   executeString += argument
   executeString += '"'

executeString += "])"
print(executeString)
>>> subprocess.run([localconfig_data["exe"], "--arg1", "--arg2", "--arg3"])
```

If one argument contains more than one word, such as "--argument value", you just pass this as 2 following values, as "--argument", "value".

Answer (score 1):

The [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) function expects the whole command as list of arguments. So assuming you'd want to execute the command

```
$ "C:\Path\To\game.exe" --arg --arg2 --arg3 abc --arg4 xyz
```

you need to call `subprocess.run` with the list `['C:\Path\To\game.exe', '--arg', '--arg2', '--arg3', 'abc', '--arg4', 'xyz']`:

```py
subprocess.run(['C:\Path\To\game.exe', '--arg', '--arg2', '--arg3', 'abc', '--arg4', 'xyz'])
```

The problem with the way you do it, is that you put a list inside of an other list, you need all the arguments on the same level. You can acieve this by unpacking the arguments list into the calling list.

```py
>>> ['app.exe', args_list]
['app.exe', ['--editor', '--erode 100', '--hidden-hud']]
>>> ['app.exe', *args_list] # unpacking
['app.exe', '--editor', '--erode 100', '--hidden-hud']
```

So:

```py
subprocess.run([localconfig_data["exe"], *args_string])
```

Your attempt with the list was right, list comprehension doesn't work with fixed list elements because of scopal ambiguity (`[a, b for b in some_list]` could mean `[(a, b) for b in some_list]` as well as `[a, (b) for b in some_list]`, hence the insistence on parantheses).